# javascript recursive function does not work properly

Tags: javascript, recursion, momentjs

I created a javascript recursive function to adjust a date: if the date is saturday or sunday or a US public holiday, then the date is rolled to the next day until the relevant date is not a holiday. I use 'moment.js' package and the related 'moment-holiday.js' file.

The code is as follows:

```
<!doctype html>

<script src="moment.js"></script>
<script src="moment-holiday.js"></script>

<script>
function CalcDueDate(dueDate){
    var dueDay = moment(dueDate).day();
    console.log(dueDay);
    if(dueDay == 0 || dueDay == 6 || IsUSHoliday(dueDate) !== undefined ){
      dueDate = moment(dueDate).add(1, 'day').format();
      console.log('a', dueDate);
      CalcDueDate(dueDate);
      } 

    console.log('b', dueDate);
    return dueDate;

}

d = "2018-05-19"
var finalDue = CalcDueDate(d);
console.log(finalDue);

</script>
```

When I ran it, the result was:

```
6                                moment3.html:12 
a 2018-05-20T00:00:00+07:00      moment3.html:9 
0                                moment3.html:12 
a 2018-05-21T00:00:00+07:00      moment3.html:9 
1                                moment3.html:16 
b 2018-05-21T00:00:00+07:00      moment3.html:16 
b 2018-05-21T00:00:00+07:00      moment3.html:16 
b 2018-05-20T00:00:00+07:00      moment3.html:23 
2018-05-20T00:00:00+07:00
```

The first 'b' and the date '2018-05-21' was as expected, but I don't understand why the second and third 'b' appeared, and brought the date back to '2018-05-20'. Can someone tell me where I did wrong in my code?
Thanks.

Comment: A cursory glance tells me you should be doing `dueDate = CalcDueDate(dueDate);` instead of just `CalcDueDate(dueDate);`

Answer (score 1):

A recursive function generally returns either a value like an edge case, or the value of a recursive call. You are currently returning once for both cases. So not only are you getting the extra `console.logs()` you are getting an incorrect final return value of 5/20/18, which is a Sunday. The fix is to make sure you return one OR the other with something like:

```
function CalcDueDate(dueDate){
    var dueDay = moment(dueDate).day();
    console.log(dueDay);
    if(dueDay == 0 || dueDay == 6 || IsUSHoliday(dueDate) !== undefined ){
      dueDate = moment(dueDate).add(1, 'day').format();
      console.log('a', dueDate);
      // return the result of recursion.
      return CalcDueDate(dueDate);
      }
    else { // you actually don't need the else -- just here to make it clearer.
        // OR return the edge case
        console.log('b', dueDate);
        return dueDate;    
    }
}
```